# How can I dynamically style sections of text in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Say I had text that the user was inputting into a big text box. I also want my app to be testing if any of the text inputted is in an array, and if it finds them then style these differently (For example highlight them wit ha yellow background). So if the phrases I was looking for were 'cake is great', 'people are awful' and 'scooters are the best', and the user wrote 'I really love my cake, cake is great' is it possible for flutter to see this text, and add a text style purely to the last part of the sentence, or otherwise style it differently?

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: see `RichText` class

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

For detailed info Refer [Custom Styling Text Formatting](https://medium.com/@dtejaswini.06/simplifying-text-formatting-in-flutter-a-guide-to-custom-styling-with-regex-699035829445)

Please try this

`OUTPUT`
[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const Scaffold(
        body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              FusionTextWidgets(
                text:
                    "Flutter is an [open-source] mobile app {star} development framework created by [Google]",
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 15),
              FusionTextWidgets(
                text:
                    "ఫ్లట్టర్ అనేది [Google] రూపొందించిన [ఓపెన్-సోర్స్] మొబైల్ యాప్ {star} డెవలప్‌మెంట్ ఫ్రేమ్‌వర్క్.",
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 15),
              FusionTextWidgets(
                text:
                    "फ़्लटर एक [ओपन-सोर्स] मोबाइल ऐप {स्टार} डेवलपमेंट फ्रेमवर्क है जो [Google] द्वारा बनाया गया है",
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 15),
              FusionTextWidgets(
                text:
                    "Flutter ಎಂಬುದು [Google] ನಿಂದ ರಚಿಸಲ್ಪಟ್ಟ [ಓಪನ್-ಸೋರ್ಸ್] ಮೊಬೈಲ್ ಅಪ್ಲಿಕೇಶನ್ {star} ಅಭಿವೃದ್ಧಿ ಚೌಕಟ್ಟಾಗಿದೆ",
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FusionTextWidgets extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  static final regex = RegExp(r"\[(.*?)\]|\{(.*?)\}");

  const FusionTextWidgets({Key? key, required this.text}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final matches = regex.allMatches(text);

    final widgets = <InlineSpan>[];
    int currentIndex = 0;

    for (final match in matches) {
      final beforeText = text.substring(currentIndex, match.start);

      if (beforeText.isNotEmpty) {
        widgets.add(
          TextSpan(
            text: beforeText,
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 14.0,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }

      if (match.group(1) != null) {
        widgets.add(
          TextSpan(
            text: match.group(1),
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 16.0,
              color: Colors.black,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
        );
      } else if (match.group(2) != null) {
        widgets.add(
          const WidgetSpan(
            child: Icon(
              Icons.star,
              size: 16,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }

      currentIndex = match.end;
    }

    final remainingText = text.substring(currentIndex);
    print("remainingText: $remainingText");
    if (remainingText.isNotEmpty) {
      widgets.add(
        TextSpan(
          text: remainingText,
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 14.0,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    return RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        children: widgets,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```